# fscanf counting "invisible" spaces

Tags: c, input, matrix, scanf

I am currently working on program that gets information from a .txt file and that needs to store it in a matrix. When I am just printing the file I use this next couple line of codes:

```
void read_maze(struct maze *mazePointer) {

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("map1.txt", "r");

    int counter = 0;
    int column = 0;
    char mazeContent[99999];

    if(fp != NULL) {

        while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &mazeContent[counter]) == 1){

            int row = counter % 10;
            printf("%c", mazeContent[counter]);

            counter++;

            if (row == 9) {
                column ++;
            }               
        } 

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Notice that im not yet using the "row" and "column" variables, this is just purely for the next coming example! From this lines of code I get the following output:

```
##########
#    #   #
# ##   #S#
# ########
#       E#
##########
```

It looks fine but as soon as I add the column and row variables to them, I need to store them in a matrix so thats why I need to column and row to be correctly fitted, I get the following output.

```
#(0,0)#(0,1)#(0,2)#(0,3)#(0,4)#(0,5)#(0,6)#(0,7)#(0,8)#(0,9)
(1,0)#(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)#(1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9)#(2,0)
(2,1)#(2,2) (2,3)#(2,4)#(2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8)#(2,9)S(3,0)#(3,1)
(3,2)#(3,3) (3,4)#(3,5)#(3,6)#(3,7)#(3,8)#(3,9)#(4,0)#(4,1)#(4,2)
(4,3)#(4,4) (4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) (5,0) (5,1)E(5,2)#(5,3)
(5,4)#(5,5)#(5,6)#(5,7)#(5,8)#(5,9)#(6,0)#(6,1)#(6,2)#(6,3)#(6,4)
```

This is not the same. As you notice my function counts the space in the beginning of line 2 and the rest while there is no space in my .txt file. It totally messes up everything since I cant sign the numbers at the designated place in the matrix. Does anyone knows what's going wrong because unfortunately I can't find it.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%c", &mazeContent[counter]);` also reads in newlines, and, if there are any because your file comes from Windows, carriage returns (`'\r'`).

Comment: I get your point. Unfortunately I can't skip the spaces because that will destroy my maze. Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Use `fgetc` and check whether the character you got needs to be ignored? (Well, you can do that also with what you have, just add `if (mazeContents[counter] == '\r') continue;` [plus possibly other comparisons for ignoring] to the top of the loop.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I changed the fscanf to fgets and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a "fgets" while loop did the trick!

```
    if(fp != NULL) {
            while (fgets(line, 12, fp) != NULL){

                for(int indexChar = 0; indexChar < 10; indexChar ++) {
                    printf("%c(%i)", line[indexChar], indexChar);
                }
                printf("\n");           
            } 
            fclose(fp);
    }
```

The output:

```
#(0)#(1)#(2)#(3)#(4)#(5)#(6)#(7)#(8)#(9)
#(0) (1) (2) (3) (4)#(5) (6) (7) (8)#(9)
#(0) (1)#(2)#(3) (4) (5) (6)#(7)S(8)#(9)
#(0) (1)#(2)#(3)#(4)#(5)#(6)#(7)#(8)#(9)
#(0) (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7)E(8)#(9)
#(0)#(1)#(2)#(3)#(4)#(5)#(6)#(7)#(8)#(9)
```